# Google Test Framework: is better to use shadowing or virtual methods?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest, googlemock

In the example below, I want to unit test `class A` in order to verify that when `A::request` is called, `B::response()` is called as well:

```
class A
{
public:
    void request()
    {
        m_b.response();
    }

private:
    B m_b;
};

class B
{ 
public:
    void response();
};
```

In order to do that, `class B` has to be mocked:

```
class MockB : public B
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0( response, void());
};
```

So that the test will contain:

```
class TestA : public A
{
    ...
};

...
EXPECT_CALL( m_b, response( ) ).Times( 1 );
request( );
...
```

The question is: how to "inject" `MockB` as a replacement of `B m_b`?

**First tecnique**:
Create a `ShadowB` class that redirects the method call to `class MockB`. This requires the original code to be in an external binary, but does not require any change in the actual code.

**Second tecnique**:

- Making `B::response` `virtual`
- Changing `B m_b` to a `std::unique_ptr<B> m_b`
- Replace `m_b` value with an instance of `class MockB` during the test setup

Second approach means more code change and I'm not sure about its pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of solving your problem is the second technique. More generally, it is very hard to 'retro-fit' unit testing code onto components that were not designed with it in mind - you almost always need to significantly modify the code being tested.

Using virtual functions to substitute Mock callback objects in place of real ones, both inheriting from a common interface is a very common approach. Another alternative is to have your classes being tested be template classes, and replace their template parameters with Mock objects.

Comment: So you are basically suggesting a test driven design approach. Very interesting the template technique. That would be a huge impact in the code by the way (much code to be moved to header and inline files).

Comment: Yes I quite like many aspects of test driven design, though I don't follow it religiously. I think though that even if you don't create a unit test for every little scenario that could possibly happen before even writing the implementation (which TDD would preach you should), you'll still find adding testing as an afterthought pretty hard, with some serious code redesign - you just can't get away from it, testing is intrusive. Personally I like to template almost everything I write so I can apply Mock template parameters